# Multiple Modals on one page

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I'm using a jQuery plugin for responsive, accessible modal popups. I'd like to have numerous popups on one page, but the script is written in a way that acts on id not class. I know ids must be unique, so obviously this won't work. I don't want to re-write the script for each instance. I'm sure there is another way, I just keep going in circles trying to figure it out. Is there a simple solution? If so, can you show me?
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Larkin_A/uua2hp8w/)

```
<button class="my_popup_open">Open First Popup</button> 

<button class="my_popup_open">Open Second Popup</button>

<div id="my_popup">...1st popup content...
<button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>
</div>

<div id="my_popup">...2nd popup content...
<button class="my_popup_close">Close</button>
</div>


<script src="http://vast-engineering.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#my_popup').popup();
});
```

Comment: As with many plugins, if a plugin doesn't offer the features you need, find another one that does. There are no shortage of modal plugins available

Comment: I've tried so many, where one problem is solved another is created. Do you have a recommendation? I want responsive, accessible, multiple modals per page, close by clicking overlay or close button, overflow scroll…all in well written efficient code